# how to display numbers from MySQL database as stars with PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table that stores feedbacks about tutors and the rating (out of 5) which other users give them.

Following is my code where I fetch data from database:

```
<?php foreach ($tut_feedback as $tf) { ?>    
    <div class="">        
        <h4 class="title"><strong><?php echo $tf->std_name;</strong></h4>
        <span class="meta"><?php echo $tf->newdate_time; ?></span>
        <span class="rating"><?php echo $tf->tutor_rating; ?></span>  // display numbers like 2,3,4
        <p class="description"><?php echo $tf->feedback_description; ?></p> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

My question is how can I display the numbers as stars. For example, if a tutor has rating of 4, I want to display 4 stars instead of the number..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the tutor rating you can run one for loop:-

```
$rating = $tf->tutor_rating;
for($i=0; $i<$rating; $i++) {
    echo "<img src='star.png' alt='*'>";
}
```

Comment: How can I display the star image instead of the keyword *

Comment: You can replace it by your star image using image tag <img src" "'>